# KVM virt-install issue

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-install

I want to run arch linux as guest but after virt-install screen is stuck at console Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ]).However VMs install by virt-manager are working fine and console is also working fine. I have enable gettS0 service.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.